# Get RSA Private Key in RAW format

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, private-key, phpseclib

I was working on a Project which purely involves PROVEN Mathematical equations, One of step requires value of private key, not for decryption or encryption.

In RSA we do have (e,n) as public key, (d,n) as private key. I am using phpseclib RSA implementation, there's option for us to get public key in RAW format, but there's none for private key. I came to know from documentation that phpseclib's RSA pads & then encrypts (Which I do not want, as application is purely a mathematical).

Solution for me would be to get either of following two

(a) Get Private Key in Raw Format.

(b) Use some other implementation of RSA which gives me RAW values of both Private Key & Public Key or if there's none implement my own RSA algorithm.

I did go through documentation of phpseclib, no useful solution was found. My question may not be properly formatted, but any help in this matter is welcome. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load the key you could probably do something like this:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('...');
echo $rsa->modulus;
echo $rsa->exponent; // private exponent
echo $rsa->publicExponent;
echo $rsa->exponents[1]; // dp
echo $rsa->exponents[2]; // dq
echo $rsa->coefficients[2]; // inverseq
echo $rsa->primes[1]; // p
echo $rsa->primes[2]; // q
```